# Ignoring HTML content when searching a table with ListJS

Tags: jquery, listjs

I'm using [ListJS](https://listjs.com/) 1.5.0 to paginate and filter records based on the user's input in the search **input**. It works fine, except for one small detail: The match is not ignoring the `html` portions of the contents. For example, the first item has this content inside the `name` cell:

```
Shirt Antman
<br><span class="badge badge-secondary">8237191</span>
```

If type **Antman** in the search box, it filters the table with the only record that has that content in the name cell (that's fine). But if type **class** it also finds that record, and of course all the other records, that have an html tag with a classname. I need a way to ignore html tags when filtering the records. I've looked into the [List API](https://listjs.com/api/) options, properties and methods without success.

[image: Searching for class returns all rows that contain an html tag with a classname]

**JavaScript**

```
var list_options = {
    valueNames: ['id','name','cat','price','views','photos','flg_featured','flg_public'],
    pagination: true,
    page: 20
};
var list = new List('list', list_options);
list.on('searchComplete', function(){
    if(list.searched) {
        console.log('Visible items: ' + list.visibleItems.length);
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="list">
<p><strong>Search</strong><br>
    <input type="search" id="search" class="search form-control form-control-lg" value="" maxlength="50">
</p>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="sort asc" data-sort="name">Product</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sort d-none d-sm-table-cell" data-sort="cat">Category</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sort money" data-sort="price">Precio</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sort number d-none d-sm-table-cell" data-sort="views">Views</th>
            <th scope="col" class="sort number d-none d-sm-table-cell" data-sort="photos">Photos</th>
            <th scope="col" class="boolean">Featured</th>
            <th scope="col" class="boolean">Active</th>
            <th scope="col" class="action">&nbsp;</th>
            <th scope="col" class="action">&nbsp;</th>
            <th scope="col" class="action">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="list">
        <tr>
            <td class="id d-none">50</td>
            <td class="name">Shirt Antman
                <br><span class="badge badge-secondary">8237191</span>
            </td>
            <td class="cat d-none d-sm-table-cell">Ropa <i class="icon icon-chevron-right"></i> Shirts</td>
            <td class="price money">12.00</td>
            <td class="views number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="photos number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-times text-muted"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-check text-success"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.edit.php?id=50" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar"><i class="icon icon-pencil"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.view.php?id=50" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver item"><i class="icon icon-file"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="#" data-action="delete" data-id="50" data-row="773cbb4725991e7dc4625c305a830987" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar"><i class="icon icon-times-circle"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-warning">
            <td class="id d-none">62</td>
            <td class="name">Shirt Ariel
                <br><span class="badge badge-secondary">8833191</span>
            </td>
            <td class="cat d-none d-sm-table-cell">Ropa <i class="icon icon-chevron-right"></i> Shirts</td>
            <td class="price money">58.00</td>
            <td class="views number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="photos number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-check text-success"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-check text-success"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.edit.php?id=62" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar"><i class="icon icon-pencil"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.view.php?id=62" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver item"><i class="icon icon-file"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="#" data-action="delete" data-id="62" data-row="8243df426471beb65c61a7640a140da6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar"><i class="icon icon-times-circle"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="id d-none">53</td>
            <td class="name">Shirt Banshee
                <br><span class="badge badge-secondary">8537191</span>
            </td>
            <td class="cat d-none d-sm-table-cell">Ropa <i class="icon icon-chevron-right"></i> Shirts</td>
            <td class="price money">15.00</td>
            <td class="views number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="photos number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-times text-muted"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-check text-success"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.edit.php?id=53" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar"><i class="icon icon-pencil"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.view.php?id=53" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver item"><i class="icon icon-file"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="#" data-action="delete" data-id="53" data-row="a4fc66273597eece770cfe359b249695" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar"><i class="icon icon-times-circle"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="id d-none">48</td>
            <td class="name">Shirt Batman
                <br><span class="badge badge-secondary">9837191</span>
            </td>
            <td class="cat d-none d-sm-table-cell">Ropa</td>
            <td class="price money">18.00</td>
            <td class="views number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="photos number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-times text-muted"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-check text-success"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.edit.php?id=48" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar"><i class="icon icon-pencil"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.view.php?id=48" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver item"><i class="icon icon-file"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="#" data-action="delete" data-id="48" data-row="9cc355b7453b437409ce3292592b37eb" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar"><i class="icon icon-times-circle"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="id d-none">63</td>
            <td class="name">Shirt Cable
                <br><span class="badge badge-secondary">8834191</span>
            </td>
            <td class="cat d-none d-sm-table-cell">--</td>
            <td class="price money">59.00</td>
            <td class="views number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="photos number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-times text-muted"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-check text-success"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.edit.php?id=63" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar"><i class="icon icon-pencil"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.view.php?id=63" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver item"><i class="icon icon-file"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="#" data-action="delete" data-id="63" data-row="7c32a52158abe9d6ed711133bb3e728b" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar"><i class="icon icon-times-circle"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="id d-none">39</td>
            <td class="name">Shirt Capitan América
                <br><span class="badge badge-secondary">8837191</span>
            </td>
            <td class="cat d-none d-sm-table-cell">Ropa <i class="icon icon-chevron-right"></i> Shirts</td>
            <td class="price money">15.00</td>
            <td class="views number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="photos number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-times text-muted"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-check text-success"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.edit.php?id=39" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar"><i class="icon icon-pencil"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.view.php?id=39" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver item"><i class="icon icon-file"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="#" data-action="delete" data-id="39" data-row="fa14b8d6ccce684b16e012ad1612dda0" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar"><i class="icon icon-times-circle"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="id d-none">65</td>
            <td class="name">Shirt Colossus
                <br><span class="badge badge-secondary">8836191</span>
            </td>
            <td class="cat d-none d-sm-table-cell">Ropa <i class="icon icon-chevron-right"></i> Shirts</td>
            <td class="price money">52.00</td>
            <td class="views number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="photos number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-times text-muted"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-check text-success"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.edit.php?id=65" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar"><i class="icon icon-pencil"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.view.php?id=65" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver item"><i class="icon icon-file"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="#" data-action="delete" data-id="65" data-row="73f88b25670bc3d0c0a29a420a83c169" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar"><i class="icon icon-times-circle"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="id d-none">3</td>
            <td class="name">Shirt Conmemorativa</td>
            <td class="cat d-none d-sm-table-cell">Ropa <i class="icon icon-chevron-right"></i> Shirts</td>
            <td class="price money">59.00</td>
            <td class="views number d-none d-sm-table-cell">5</td>
            <td class="photos number d-none d-sm-table-cell">5</td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-check text-success"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-check text-success"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.edit.php?id=3" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar"><i class="icon icon-pencil"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.view.php?id=3" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver item"><i class="icon icon-file"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="#" data-action="delete" data-id="3" data-row="57049fcae700a38fca2a2cec333adb93" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar"><i class="icon icon-times-circle"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="id d-none">61</td>
            <td class="name">Shirt Dagger
                <br><span class="badge badge-secondary">8807191</span>
            </td>
            <td class="cat d-none d-sm-table-cell">Ropa <i class="icon icon-chevron-right"></i> Shirts</td>
            <td class="price money">57.00</td>
            <td class="views number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="photos number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-times text-muted"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-check text-success"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.edit.php?id=61" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar"><i class="icon icon-pencil"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.view.php?id=61" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver item"><i class="icon icon-file"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="#" data-action="delete" data-id="61" data-row="d1ef2e4c6bc68e922b8b5086710e4c30" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar"><i class="icon icon-times-circle"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="id d-none">67</td>
            <td class="name">Shirt Dazzler
                <br><span class="badge badge-secondary">8837991</span>
            </td>
            <td class="cat d-none d-sm-table-cell">--</td>
            <td class="price money">15.00</td>
            <td class="views number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="photos number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-times text-muted"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-check text-success"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.edit.php?id=67" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar"><i class="icon icon-pencil"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.view.php?id=67" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver item"><i class="icon icon-file"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="#" data-action="delete" data-id="67" data-row="0db0e976eea168de09560ae03785a461" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar"><i class="icon icon-times-circle"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="id d-none">66</td>
            <td class="name">Shirt Deadpool
                <br><span class="badge badge-secondary">8837191</span>
            </td>
            <td class="cat d-none d-sm-table-cell">Ropa <i class="icon icon-chevron-right"></i> Shirts</td>
            <td class="price money">13.00</td>
            <td class="views number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="photos number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-times text-muted"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-check text-success"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.edit.php?id=66" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar"><i class="icon icon-pencil"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.view.php?id=66" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver item"><i class="icon icon-file"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="#" data-action="delete" data-id="66" data-row="dd7793ed3b3212093298d9fc72893c86" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar"><i class="icon icon-times-circle"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="id d-none">47</td>
            <td class="name">Shirt Flash
                <br><span class="badge badge-secondary">8837191</span>
            </td>
            <td class="cat d-none d-sm-table-cell">Ropa <i class="icon icon-chevron-right"></i> Shirts</td>
            <td class="price money">17.00</td>
            <td class="views number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="photos number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-times text-muted"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-check text-success"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.edit.php?id=47" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar"><i class="icon icon-pencil"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.view.php?id=47" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver item"><i class="icon icon-file"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="#" data-action="delete" data-id="47" data-row="4c932d6070de8411f31796c92c33be21" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar"><i class="icon icon-times-circle"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="id d-none">58</td>
            <td class="name">Shirt Gambit
                <br><span class="badge badge-secondary">8857191</span>
            </td>
            <td class="cat d-none d-sm-table-cell">Ropa <i class="icon icon-chevron-right"></i> Shirts</td>
            <td class="price money">54.00</td>
            <td class="views number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="photos number d-none d-sm-table-cell">0</td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-times text-muted"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="boolean"><i class="icon icon-check text-success"></i>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.edit.php?id=58" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar"><i class="icon icon-pencil"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="products.view.php?id=58" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver item"><i class="icon icon-file"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="action"><a href="#" data-action="delete" data-id="58" data-row="0ed400f2cb9efb4c49e7498968bc71ab" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar"><i class="icon icon-times-circle"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot><tr><td colspan="11"><nav aria-label="Pages"><ul class="pagination pagination-sm"></ul></nav></td></tr></tfoot>
</table>
<div>
```

I've added a live example here: https://jsitor.com/g2vfIazy1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just added one line to fix this in the source code of the file list.js and I made an exact example of what you have and it did work for me, hope it works for you as well.

Just search for this code sample in your .js file and add the pointed line to it.

```
<script>
    values: function(values, value, searchArgument) {
        if (values.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
            var text = toString(values[value]).toLowerCase();
            text = text.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig," "); // this is the line I added

            if (fuzzy(text, searchArgument, options)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```